# How to add wait for the test?

Tags: webdriver-io

I am using WebdriverIO for the following test

```
webdriverio
    .remote(options)
    .init()
    .url('http://www.google.com')
    .getTitle().then(function(title) {
        console.log('Title was: ' + title);
    })
    .end();
```

However, my ISP provide a web virus checking page between google.com, so the test always return the virus checking page title. How can I make sure the result always return Google?

Answer (score 4):

Using pauses in your tests is a bad practice. It's better to use explicit waits instead.

E.g. you can use waitUntil method, provided by Wdio API. So, you can create helper function to wait for expected URL.

Here is the example in ES6:

```
function waitForUrl(url, timeout) {
  browser.waitUntil(() => browser.getUrl().includes(url)
  }, timeout, `Expected url must be ${url}`)
}
```

You can simply pass function (or promise) as waitUntil condition along with timeout (in ms), error message and interval (also in ms, default value is 500ms). So, waitUntil will be waiting until that condition is fulfilled with a truthy value. Otherwise, error will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pause(time)` function to pause your test for a while till you are redirected to Google.

```
webdriverio
.remote(options)
.init()
.url('http://www.google.com')
.pause(5000)
.getTitle().then(function(title) {
    console.log('Title was: ' + title);
})
.end();
```

Comment: Don't use pauses in your test. Use explicit waits instead.